# How to identify Android Support Library versions in gradle?

Tags: android, android-support-library

Whenever a new Android Support Repository is released, I have to update my dependencies in the app Gradle file.

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
}`

However, I don't get much of a clue as to what version to add i.e.: 25.1.1 with every release unless I go and check the [Recent Support Revisions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html).
The version shown in the Android SDK Manager: Android Support Repository, **revision 44**.

*I want to know how to get the right version given the revision number of the Android Support Repository during updates*.
All other version such as Build tools show the right corresponding versions, only this one stumps me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **latest.release** suffix in for your libraries like this:

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:latest.release'`

It will insure you are always using the latest release version.

Answer (score 0):

The revision number isn't really that important.

The support library major version should match the `compileSdk`.